# ssh-copy-id asking for password

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, ssh-keys

I am trying to use `ssh-copy-id` to copy a ssh key but I get asked for a password after I type this command `ssh-copy-id -i deploy_rsa.pub deploy@multicrew.co.uk`.

I am not sure why its asking for a password seeing as I did not set a password for the key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The password you are asked to insert is your ssh user password. You need to have ssh access to the remote computer in order to add the ssh key. If this password wasn't asked anyone that know your username can add their ssh key to your remote computer and have direct access to your account.

Just insert your ssh password when asked! If the key is copied successfully, you won't be asked for a password again from this computer.

Answer (score 1):

It is asking for the password of the remote server you want to connect to. It is a one time process.